# Audio notes & voice recording stop abruptly in Google Keep

Tags: voice-recognition, google-keep, voice-recording

I've recently been trying Google Keep for its speech-to-text feature. The problem I'm having though is that it only records a couple of seconds then stops; usually about 2 to 7 seconds.

I tried it several ways and made sure my fingers aren't on the screen while I'm recording, so I don't think I'm accidentally tapping the screen to stop the recording.

Is the problem likely with my phone, or is there some setting I need to change? I assume I don't need to upgrade $ to make notes that are longer, do I?

Comment: Send this as a bug report to google. I don't think there is much you can do.

Answer (score 2):

After trying the voice recording I've found that the recording stops whenever there is silence for a few seconds. In other words, to make a long recording you'll need to talk continously.

I've so far found no way to increase the length of this silence period in order to stop the recorder from prematurely stop recording. Please comment if you know how to do that.

Comment: what's more, it stops recording after around a minute!  i'm posting a new question related to this.